# Wordpress Post Links With Wrong Day

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento

I am having a strange issue with a new multi-site wordpress installation. This is installed on a Magento website.

I can see my blog and go into the admin area just fine. However, when I click on a post I get a 404 error. If I change the day in the url it will work.

**Example:** If the link takes me to mysite.com/dev/devsite/default/blog/2013/11/11/hello-world/ I get the 404. But, if I manually change the day in the url to mysite.com/dev/devsite/default/blog/2013/11/12/hello-world/ I can see the post.

Here is my .htaccess file that the multi-site wordpress told me to use.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/devsite/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a WP MultiSite installation under my main website. Here's the .htaccess code used by my site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Try using this instead of your ones. There is a  ending too in your code, I think you copied the code wrong way.